# Almost periodic functions

Tags: functional-analysis, almost-periodic-functions

Given a locally compact Abelian group $G$, consider the Banach algebra $l^{\infty}(G)$.  Is there some condition such that the algebra $AP(G) \subset l^{\infty}(G)$ of all almost-periodic functions is dense in $l^{\infty}(G)$?

Comment: (+1) good question! I'll think about it, well.. if it is separating points then it's dense.

Comment: The following fact might be useful: $AP(G)$ is the closure in $L^{\infty} (G)$ of the linear space of trigonometric polynomials on $G$.